# Firebase error: localhost refused to connect

Tags: firebase, android-studio, localhost

I am making an android application on android studio in which I need to use firebase. I have made a project in firebase and also connected my project to it.

At the last step it says "Your Firebase Android app has been created in Firebase" but when I click on "CONNECT" there pops an error "This site cannot be reached. localhost refused to connect." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use Assistant in Android Studio? It should take you through step by step instruction. Assistant will be available through menu in Android Studio: Tools -> Firebase. Do not forget to add your app in Firebase ("+Add app") in the main page of your Firebase project.